# How to get questions details by their Id in LimeSurvey

Tags: php, yii, limesurvey

I m trying to get the question details from the database by giving the question ID . i check their documentation plus unable to find thing form the api

Comment: pls post your database schema...

Comment: you can check from the link

https://manual.limesurvey.org/LimeSurvey_1.8_database_layout_documentation

Comment: show the model question (master and detail) and the controller action where you want get the question details

Answer (score 0):

Best solution : use API : http://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html#method_get_question_properties

ALternative : look at code https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/master/application/models/Question.php#L78